# Excel conditional formatting when part of validation list

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting on a cell that is populated via a validation list.  It will not format.  I try the exact same formatting on another cell which is not populated from a drop down list, and it formats the way I want it to.  Does Excel not allow conditional formatting for items populated from drop down lists?

Comment: I can't replicate this.  I created a validation range, then had a bunch of cells validate using a list, pulled from the validation range.  Conditional formatting worked fine.

Comment: What is your conditional formatting equation and formatting and which cell is it applied to?

Comment: I have a validation list for column G.  There are 3 choices for this list (open, canceled and reported).  I want to format the cell in red if "canceled" is chosen.  I use the conditional formatting as follows:

Comment: cell value is     equal to     "canceled"

Comment: I found something interesting.  I can format for other options from this validation list.  If I choose "open" it will format as I want it to.  Excel does not seem to like the word "canceled" for some reason?  I changed the option to read "canceled request" and the formatting is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that you had a hidden space in your data validation so that your cell's value was "Canceled " instead of "Canceled". That would prevent your conditional formatting from matching.

For example, if you type in the list of words in the Source field, Data Validation ignores spaces after a comma but not spaces before a comma. The below screen print will cause the problem I described.

[image: Data validation dialog box]

Comment: this might actually be the cause